# hadoop 2.6.0 testing samples.

Tags: hadoop, testing, mapreduce

I have a 2 slave nodes mini cluster hadoop system and trying to do some tests on it. **The system is successfully configured with hadoop 2.6.0 and I've done the  WordCount test on it**. Is there any other good testing examples  other than the WordCount? (perhaps more pratical test deal with bigger data) With open sourced code? I 've seen most of the examples out of the google search, but either the hadoop version is too old, or there are no souce code to test them. I like the one: *Using Hadoop to analyze the full Wikipedia dump files using WikiHadoop*, though the hadoop version is way to old. If anyone knows there is a newer version, will be great (any similar one will be good) ... TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in a project to exemplify the different features in Hadoop MapReduce framework. It is still in progress, but there are different versions of the WordCount job using modern API's (Java and Hadoop).

It include *utils* to generate test input files. But with small changes you could use it to process your own test files. Like modifying the follow line in the mappers to split using spaces or commas.

```
String[] words = line.split("\t");
```

https://github.com/lalosam/HadoopInExamples